# Show that $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}<\frac{P(X>x)}{\phi(x)}<\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ where $X$~$N(0,1)$ with pdf $\phi(x)$.

Tags: probability, inequality, normal-distribution

I tried taking exponentials and using Markov's Inequality, but this only gave me an upper bound of $\sqrt{2\pi}$. I'm not sure how to begin to approach this question - can anyone give a hint?

Comment: Did you try directly, $\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} -\frac{1}{x} =h(x)$?

Comment: @Alex I tried finding $h'(x)$, but I still got an expression containing $P(X>x)$ so I wasn't sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: I haven't tried,  but derivative of $\Phi$ is $\phi$, also at 0 this right inequality holds

Comment: @StubbornAtom That question does give the upper bound, but not the lower bound (as far as I can see), so it answers half of the question. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: No it completely answers your question. Look at the answer by Prof. Sarwate.

Comment: @StubbornAtom You're right, I just looked and their answer does give exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these known ["double inequality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function) for the Gaussian (Bounds and Approximations in "Q-function", Wikipedia)

Applying this double inequality to your exercise you immediately get

$\frac{x}{x^2+1}<\frac{\mathbb{P}[X>x]}{\phi(x)}<\frac{1}{x}$

To prove what you need it is enough to prove that, for $x>0$,

$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}<\frac{x}{x^2+1}$